# Dropdown-Menu with optgroup

Tags: perl, cgi, drop-down-menu, optgroup

i am trying to create a dynamic dropdown-menu that receives its entries out of an xml-file at script-startup.
first i tried a static version like this:

```
Tr(td([popup_menu( -name=>'betreff', -values=>[optgroup(-name=>'Mädels', 
-values=>['Susi','Steffi',''], -labels=>{'Susi'=>'Petra','Steffi'=>'Paula'})
,optgroup(-name=>'Jungs', -values=>['moe', 'catch',''])])]));
```

that worked fine.

The prob starts when i try to put the -values-parameter of popup_menu into a scalar variable.
Should somehow lokk similar to that one:

```
$popup_values = "[optgroup(-name=>'Mädels', -values=>['Susi','Steffi',''], 
-labels=>{'Susi'=>'Petra','Steffi'=>'Paula'}),optgroup(-name=>'Jungs', 
-values=>['moe', 'catch',''])]"
```

or with single quotation marks.

The goal is to build that string by concatenating the syntax-corrected elements of the xml-file. Thats because i do not know a priori how many optgroups or list elements within the optgroups will exist.
Any idea?

Thx in advance

Jochen

Answer (score 1):

So you have an XML file which you use to generate that string? Why not directly generate the data structure necessary for the `popup_menu` call? It's just an array (you can call `optgroup` while "analysing" the XML file)

If you really want to use the string-solution then you could use [eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) to transform the string to the data structure. Though this solution has certain security issues.

### Reading From XML-File

Here's an example of how to transform form XML to the optgroup, this of course depends on how your XML-file looks like.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Simple;
use CGI qw/:standard/;
my $xmlString = join('', <DATA>);

my $xmlData = XMLin($xmlString);

my @popup_values;
foreach my $group (keys(%{$xmlData->{group}})) {
  my (@values, %labels);

  my $options = $xmlData->{group}->{$group}->{opt};
  foreach my $option (keys(%{$options})) {
    push @values, $option;
    if(exists($options->{$option}->{label}) &&
        '' ne $options->{$option}->{label}) {
      $labels{$option} = $options->{$option}->{label};
    }
  }

  push @popup_values, optgroup(-name => $group,
    -labels => \%labels,
    -values => \@values
  );
}


print popup_menu(-name=>'betreff', -values=> \@popup_values);

__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dropdown>
  <group name="Mädels">
    <opt name="Susi" label="Petra"/>
    <opt name="Steffi" label="Paula"/>
    <opt name="" />
  </group>
  <group name="Jungs">
    <opt name="moe" />
    <opt name="catch" />
    <opt name="" />
  </group>
</dropdown>
```

Comment: your first solution sounds interesting, but how do i realize that?
already opened filehandle and pumped the lines into an array. The next step would be manipulating the strings to match the syntax needed for the `optgroup` command. Or should I preferrably use the `xml::simple`-Package?

Comment: I think an XML-parser like XML::Simple is better suited for this task since it simplifies the access to the data you need. I have also added an example of how I would do it (I created some simple XML-format, yours might differ and thus needs probably other paths to access the data)